# Angular is not recognizing the name of the project as a Property

Tags: javascript, json, angular, web, frontend

I just installed the Angular materials from the CLI and then checked my angular.json file and now the console is showing an error in this file saying **"Property MEAN-APP is not allowed"** [*here MEAN-APP is the name of my Angular project*]

[This is my vsCode window showing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjRpZ.png)

is there anyway to fix this or should i just leave it?

Comment: According to standards, you have to give a valid name to projects however MEAN-APP is normally appropriate and valid. Nevertheless you prompt an error! Did you try to give another name to your project? like 'meanapp'?

Answer (score 0):

after 2 hour of problems with my styles i found the problem was in the angular.json, the most funny of this its yestedary workly perfect but now in the morning not.

Check the details here, i think is a problem with VS

["Property Not Allowed" in angular.json error in Visual Studio CODE for Angular CLI version 9.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61179012/property-not-allowed-in-angular-json-error-in-visual-studio-code-for-angular-c)

Comment: Please don't use link only answer. Please provide some example with context. In the future the link may not work, and your answer would be useless