# why Angular.json file is giving warning "Property featureMod is not allowed"?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

Below i am sharing image, although code is working fine but still trying to figure out what this issue could be...please help

[Image of Project in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2Rk9.png)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61179012/863110) can help

Answer (score 0):

Project naming rules, your app should be names `feature-mod`, use hyphen to separate words (kebab-case).

*you can also use Snake case (underscores)* but hyphens are better.